# Unable to SSH to vagrant Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, vagrantfile, ubuntu-server

I create very simple Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "boxcutter/ubuntu1604"
  config.vm.hostname = "r1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "1024"
  end

end
```

The general purpose to up the Ubuntu 16.04 server. And all is good excepting troubles with SSH connection.

My log:

`vagrant up`

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'boxcutter/ubuntu1604' is up to date...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 (guest) => 3000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

...

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I replace **config.vm.box = "boxcutter/ubuntu1604"**
with box name **"ubuntu/trusty64"** and it's worked well, but how to fix with 16.04 ?

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest vagrant/virtualbox there are a lot issues on older versions and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: So looks like the 'ubuntu/trusty64' I found at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search is a Desktop version of OS, not a server version. And I got *'upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr'* error issue during installation, but Vagrant don't display the error. I import and use - *vagrant box add https://atlas.hashicorp.com/gbarbieru/boxes/xenial* and it's worked well. Hope it's help somebody.

Comment: So, I solve this case adding this code to vagrantfile: vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cableconnected1", "on"]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was solved updating to the last VirtualBox and vagrant version. Try the "bento/ubuntu-16.04" vagrant box. The "ubuntu/xenial64" did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the in the error mentioned solution? The `boot_timeout` is by default on 300 seconds [[1]](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) - did you gave the boxcutter box a little more time, e.g. 600 seconds, to see if it will respond afterwards?

However next to `ubuntu/trusty64` there is also `ubuntu/xenial64` [[2]](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64) which is 16.04 - maybe you wanne try it.

Comment: I try increase timeout and I try ubuntu/xenial64 as you noticed. But with the same result..

Answer (score 0):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
 end
```

Try this may be help you.